# Почему две одинаковые переменные не проходят проверку на равенство?

Tags: python, sqlite, if

Делаю телеграм бот. Две переменные `msg` и `answer` в этом примере равны, но условие равности не работает.

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

И параллельно, как можно изменять `id` в SQL запросе. Например, сделать чтобы выпадал вопрос с рандомным `id` каждый раз. Если просто подставляю переменную из цикла рандомного вместо цифры, не работает.

```
def check_answer(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT answer FROM questions WHERE id=3")
    answer = cursor.fetchone()
    msg = message.text
    if msg == answer:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Правильный ответ! Идем дальше?")
    elif msg != answer:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно")
```

Comment: вы бы выводили переменные на печать перед сравнением, было бы меньше вопросов. А заодно и их типы.

Comment: ну небось answer это число, а msg это текст

Comment: @Эникейщик нет, текст и текст

Comment: Нет, `fetchone()` возвращает не текст

Comment: @strawdog Я их выводила, они одинаковые. Не знаю, зачем-то удалила эти строчки перед публикацией. А как вывести типы?

Comment: @Alexey Ten А что? И как сделать тогда сравнение значения из базы и вводимого? Простите за глупые элементарные вопросы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cursor.fetchone()` всегда возвращает кортеж (`tuple`) - даже в том случае если в запросе вы выбираете только один столбец.

Поэтому попробуйте так:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
answer = row[0] if row else None
...
```

Чтобы проверить тип переменной:

```
print(type(answer))
```

Comment: Но если данных не будет, то fetchone вернет `None`

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо за уточнение - поправил ответ)

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо! Все заработало))))